# Unable to filter a set of data for URL filtering

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have built a code that filters the data until the first occurrence. After that, it is returning all sequential data which not required. Can you please help me with the approach to solve this!!

filter URL is localdirector/index.html?filter=code2. The value to be returned only code2. but for me, code3 is also returning. Can anyone please help me with it!!

```html
<html>

<body>

<ul class="portfolio-filters list-inline">
  <li class="filter active code1" data-filter="all">code1</li>
  <li class="filter code2" data-filter="webdesign">code2</li>
  <li class="filter code3" data-filter="responsive">code3</li>
  <li class="filter code4" data-filter="wordpress">code4</li>
</ul>

<script>
const url = new URL(window.location.href)
const currentFilter = url.searchParams.get('filter')

if (currentFilter != null) {

  const collection = document.getElementsByClassName('filter')

  for (let item of collection) {
    if (item.classList.contains(currentFilter)) {
      item.style.display = 'block'
      break
    }

    item.style.display = 'none'
  }
}</script>


 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because you exit the loop

Comment: Use continue instead of break inside your for loop. break will exit the loop whereas continue will skip all below statements and move for the next iteration in loop.

Answer (score 2):

You exit the loop so the ones after it do not run

```js
// const url = new URL(window.location.href)
const url = new URL('http://www.exaple.com/index.html?filter=code2')
const currentFilter = url.searchParams.get('filter')

if (currentFilter != null) {

  const collection = document.getElementsByClassName('filter')

  for (let item of collection) {
    if (item.classList.contains(currentFilter)) {
      item.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
      item.style.display = 'none'
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="portfolio-filters list-inline">
  <li class="filter active code1" data-filter="all">code1</li>
  <li class="filter code2" data-filter="webdesign">code2</li>
  <li class="filter code3" data-filter="responsive">code3</li>
  <li class="filter code4" data-filter="wordpress">code4</li>
</ul>
```

You can just do it with a selector instead of a loop

```js
// const url = new URL(window.location.href)
const url = new URL('http://www.exaple.com/index.html?filter=code2')
const currentFilter = url.searchParams.get('filter') || 'code1';

document.querySelector(`.filter.${currentFilter}`).classList.add('active');
```

```css
.filter {
  display: none;
}

.filter.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="portfolio-filters list-inline">
  <li class="filter code1" data-filter="all">code1</li>
  <li class="filter code2" data-filter="webdesign">code2</li>
  <li class="filter code3" data-filter="responsive">code3</li>
  <li class="filter code4" data-filter="wordpress">code4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!!

Yes, I can do that. But my filter codes will be many like code2 can repeat multiple times at different places. My script has to look in for that and then give a result.

Comment: Do not know that that means. There are solutions for everything, just need to know the exact problem.